# Handling webdriverio timeouts

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, timeout

Here's what I want to accomplish:

```
check if element "Error" span exists
     then do something if it does ===
else check if element "el2" span exists
      then do something ====
else
      do something
```

Here's my code

```
let done = false;
let errorOccured = false;
let isManualStep = false;
do {
    try {
        console.log('Checking span.label-red=Error...................')
        let errorStepExists = $('span.label-red=Error').isExisting();
        if (errorStepExists) {
            console.log('Error encountered...................')

            done = true;
        }
    } else {
        console.log('Error not encountered...................')
        let el2Exists = $('span>td.col-md-2=Waiting').isExisting();
        if (mel2Exists) {
            console.log('Encountered...................')
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
while (!done);
```

It doesn't seem to go to the catch block if element doesn't exist and it fails my test instead with a timeout error.

Error: Timeout of 20000ms exceeded. The execution in the test "xxxxxx" took too long. Try to reduce the run time or increase your timeout for test specs (https://webdriver.io/docs/timeouts.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to best way to achieve your goal in your programming language binding, however the best way in java is to use the "findElements(By locator)" method of WebDriver interface.

This method returns a List. You then check for the existence of your WebElement by examining the size of this list. (If the size is not 0,  your WebElement is present).

Hope this helps you come by with a similar approach in your language binding.

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, I tried that approach too using $$ in webdriverio but timeout still fires and failed the tests. I'm mot thinking it's mocha timeout which is related to the "it" block itself.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, my test is failing with timeout error " Timeout of 60000ms exceeded." and catch block never-ever gets hit. Did you find any resolution or workaround?